# Block all files which are not rewritten by a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webpage which uses PHP and I am using `mod_rewrite` to make simpler URLs like

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /php/pages/login.php [L]
```

What I want to do is to prevent the direct access to the directory `/php`. But if I use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^php - [R=404,L,NC]
```

at the end of the file even the rewritten URLs are prevent since the .htaccess is used in the subdirectory again with the rewritten URL. If possible I would not like to place another .htaccess to each directory.
I also tried `RewriteCond` with `REQUEST_URI` without any luck.

Comment: found [END] flag but this isnt supported in apache2

Comment: Have this now at the end of my file:

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /php/
    RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]

Works but it's risky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/php/    
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```